# Удалить дубли из массива

Tags: php

Есть массив $data['products'] в виде

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 12
        [name] => def
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 12
        [name] => jkl
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 100
        [name] => sds
    )
)
```

Как из него удалить все элементы, кроме первого, с одинаковым значением ключа ID (в данном случае везде, где ID = 12) ?

Comment: Не ясно. В массиве еще могут быть дубли между собой по ID? если да - то каково условие оставить/удалить?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский может быть хоть 100 элементов с одинаковым ID. Нужно удалить все у которых значение ID совпадает, кроме одного.

Comment: а какого одного? вот будет 100 элементов  с одинаковым ID, оставлять любой первый попавшийся что ли?  вот например ID   1, 10, 1, 12, 13, 12, 10, 1.... в итоге кто первый попался с одинаковым ID того и тапки? будет 1, 10, 12, 13 и остальные что позади - в мусор, так?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо сложить все в массив, используя id как ключ. Добиться этого можно используя `array_column`. Последовательные ключи будут перезаписаны, поэтому надо реверснуть массив, чтобы получить первые вхождения на выходе.

```
$data = [
        ['id' => 12, 'v' => 'a'],  
        ['id' => 12, 'v' => 'b'],
        ['id' => 12, 'v' => 'c'],
        ['id' => 13, 'v' => 'd'],
        ['id' => 13, 'v' => 'e'],
    ];
    
$result = array_column(array_reverse($data), null, 'id');
```

При необходимости можно сбросить ключи и сделать реверс обратно

примерно то же самое можно получить вручную:

```
$idx = count($data);
$result = [];
while(--$idx >= 0){
    $id = $data[$idx]['id'];
    $result[$id] = $data[$idx];
}
```

Comment: вообще, ручной код намного эффективней. если размер массива большой то первый вариант потребует двойной памяти для решения задачи. А при  ручном решении памяти понадобится в зависимости от числа дублей, а если ссылки использовать, то только по сами указатели.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй использовать array_unique() с конкретным флагом и вообще почитай про данную функцию.
Вот пример:

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => '123',
        'foo' => 'aaa',
        'bar' => 'bbb'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '123',
        'foo' => 'ccc',
        'bar' => 'ddd'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '567',
        'foo' => 'eee',
        'bar' => 'fff'
    ]
];

$ids = array_column($array, 'id');
$ids = array_unique($ids);
$array = array_filter($array, function ($key, $value) use ($ids) {
    return in_array($value, array_keys($ids));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

На выходе будет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [foo] => aaa
            [bar] => bbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 567
            [foo] => eee
            [bar] => fff
        )

)
```

Comment: что-то на выходе пустой массив получаю

Comment: Ну значит, что-то делаешь не правильно. Только запустил свой пример на локалке, затем через print_r($array); вывел 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 123 [foo] => aaa [bar] => bbb ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 567 [foo] => eee [bar] => fff ) )

Comment: <?php

$data['products'] = [
    [
        'id' => '12',
        'name' => 'def',
    ],
    [
        'id' => '12',
        'name' => 'jkl',
    ],
    [
        'id' => '100',
        'name' => 'sds',
    ]
];


$ids = array_column($data['products'], 'id');
$ids = array_unique($ids);
$data['products'] = array_filter($data['products'], function ($key, $value) use ($ids) {
    return in_array($value, array_keys($ids));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

print_r($data['products']);
?>